# Bibliotecas são baixadas múltiplas vezes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cache, cdn

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza 3 bibliotecas (Bootstrap, jQuery, jQueryUI) em 10 páginas diferentes. Os navegadores fazem o cache das bibliotecas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Se elas estão vindo do mesmo URL e não há nenhuma indicação/configuração em contrário é para fazer cache dentro de determinadas políticas estabelecidas pelos navegadores/usuários.

Para usar o que está em cache um tentativa de leitura é feita e deve retornar `304 Not modified`.

Exatamente por isso é recomendado usar um local padrão onde já existem estas bibliotecas. Assim o seu *website* não precisar baixar o que já está no navegador do usuário. Mesmo que tenha sido baixado originalmente por outro *website*.

Costuma sair "mais barato" carregar uma biblioteca completa do [CDN da Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) ou da [própria biblioteca](https://code.jquery.com/) ou de algum [outro local](https://cdnjs.com/) do que fazer uma versão personalizada dela só com o que você usa.

[Tutorial sobre cache](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

Em geral os navegadores fazem, sim, cache. Eventualmente eles verificam por mudanças e baixam o arquivo de novo, mas na maior parte do tempo você não precisa de preocupar tanto com o desempenho.

Caso queira mudar o comportamento padrão, pode forçar isso no seu sistema ou no seu navegador alterando os cabeçalhos HTTP `Expires` e `Cache-Control`. Isso é mais que suficiente para uma intranet.

Na internet você pode usar um link para um repositório CDN, que contém as bibliotecas mais comuns. Dessa forma você economiza banda e alavanca o cache que pode ter sido feito no acesso a outros sites.

No caso do jQuery, por exemplo, você pode usar os CDNs disponibilizados no [próprio site da biblioteca](https://code.jquery.com/).

É importante atentar que, ao contrário de bibliotecas conhecidas, o cache de scripts específicos pode ser um problema se você fizer pequenas alterações ao longo do tempo. É comum usuários reclamarem de bugs que aparecem logo após atualizar a versão do sistema, sendo a solução geralmente limpar o cache.

Para evitar isso, uma das técnicas usadas é acrescentar um número de versão como parâmetro de URL ao incluir o script específico. Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-script.js?ver=1.1">
```

Atualizando a versão juntamente com as novas *releases* do sistema você vai forçar o navegador a baixar as novas versões dos scripts.