# Preciso incluir o jQuery em todas as páginas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

É necessário colocar o *script* do jQuery de produção todas as vezes que for iniciar uma nova codificação?

Comment: O que seria o "script de produção"?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Só precisa fazer a call nos documentos que você vai usar o jQuery. Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919023/trouble-making-animating-boxes-in-jquery

Comment: Obrigada! Eu preciso deixar o arquivo JS em todas as pastas que for utilizar então?

Comment: Barbara, viu a resposta abaixo? O ideal é usar um link externo, como o bigown sugeriu. Isso te dispensa de manter uma cópia do jQuery no seu projeto.

Comment: Certo. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é necessário colocar em todas as páginas que vão usá-lo. E o ideal é que sempre seja o mesmo URL, assim ele provavelmente [pegará o arquivo do cache do navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46014/101). Idealmente seria bom a carga ser feita do URL padrão da biblioteca para facilitar que o arquivo da biblioteca já esteja carregado no cache.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/IncludeJquery.html).

Obviamente não precisa colocar em páginas que não usarão nada da biblioteca.

Tem um macete pra não precisar escrever isso em toda página, mas é algo mais sofisticado e que pode não dar certo em todas situações e pode complicar o SEO se for necessário.

jQuery hoje em dia é praticamente desnecessário.

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

não necessariamente, se você for abrir uma nova "pagina" então sim, terá que carregar, mas se você usar apenas uma pagina e todas as restantes forem carregadas através de uma função javascript por exemplo, neste caso o script anterior se manterá carregado, então não precisará carregar novamente o arquivo.

exemplo no index

```
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
      ...
<script>
    $("div").load('proximaPagina.html');
</script>
</html>
```

essa "proximaPagina.html" pode ter códigos jQuery normalmente irá funcionar sem passar a tag `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` novamente