# O que é CDN e como habilitá-lo nos meus arquivos JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Em um site de verificação de performance eu recebi a mensagem de "Use a CDN for all static assets" para meus arquivos JavaScript.

O que são CDN e como implementá-los?

Comment: Crio quea  melhor resposta pra sua pergunta está na própia descrição dessa pergunta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119766/criando-um-cdn-content-delivery-network

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É **Content Delivery Network** ou rede de entrega de conteúdo. De fato costuma ser usado mais para conteúdo estático. Em geral é uma rede mundial de centros de dados (pontos de presença) que faz uma "espécie de cache" (mas não exatamente) do conteúdo que deve ser carregado por seus sites, dando melhor performance, não só porque são especializados nisso, mas também porque costumam estar mais perto de quem está requisitando o conteúdo (através de geolocalização). Desta forma desafoga seu servidor para atividades "mais nobres" como a geração de conteúdo dinâmico.

Em geral é uma rede bastante estável e confiável, além de suportar grande volume de acesso sem perder velocidade, mesmo em casos de ataques. Ele pode ser usado como uma defesa. Mesmo que perca totalmente o acesso no site porque seus servidores principais estão sofrendo ataques, ainda pode ter uma versão estática do site sendo oferecida. O importante é que ele ajuda na entrega do conteúdo. Obviamente só costuma ser bastante útil em casos de sites com razoável tráfego ou para conteúdo padrão que é universalmente usado na maioria dos sites. Mas isso não é o foco desta pergunta.

## Bibliotecas padrões

Em alguns casos é [usado por algumas bibliotecas padrões para que evite a carga desnecessária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46014/101) de algo que aquele cliente já tem localmente. Se quer apenas isso, basta usar o endereço que sua biblioteca preferida usa, conforme a pergunta *linkada* acima.

jQuery era uma dessas bibliotecas mais usadas (na época que respondi) e o endereço onde ela indica onde pegá-la do CDN deles é https://code.jquery.com/. Clicando em um deles aparecerá isto:

[image: SS jQuery]

Então use:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Cdn.html).

## Conteúdo próprio

Se pretende fazer para conteúdo do seu site (imagem, audiovisual, arquivos para download, etc.), terá que contratar o serviço com alguma empresa especializada para ter um endereço onde colocar esse conteúdo e referenciá-lo na sua página.

A maneira exata de como referencia na sua página depende de cada conteúdo. Mas não tem segredo, a única diferença é que não está no mesmo servidor que o conteúdo dinâmico, portanto o endereço do arquivo é outro local, certamente será um URL absoluto dando todo o endereço (o endereço relativo que normalmente usamos só funciona para conteúdo local. Mas é HTML comum, nada de especial.

## Complemento

Há quem use CDN para conteúdo dinâmico, principalmente transmissões ao vivo e tarefas especializadas.

O assunto é vasto, tem muito detalhe, mas precisaria de perguntas mais específicas.

Comment: Suas respostas sempre ótimas, parabéns mestre

Comment: Cara sua resposta foi muito boa.

Answer (score 3):

CDN (Content Delivery Network) é uma rede de distribuição de informação que permite fornecer conteúdo Web de uma forma mais rápida a um grande número de utilizadores, distribuindo o conteúdo por multiplos servidores.

Exemplo de CDN:

**Jquery**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Angular animate**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No contexto de desenvolvimento web (e relativo à mensagem a respeito de conteúdo estático) CDNs são serviços onde bibliotecas *client* (em geral Javascript e CSS) podem ser encontradas.

Seu foco é em alta confiabilidade (*uptime*, versionamento) e performance (taxa de transmissão). Para isso grande parte dos serviços de CDN possuem servidores geograficamente distribuídos, com o objetivo de diminuição do tempo de resposta.

Answer (score 1):

[CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) pode ser visto com um serviço que hospeda arquivos estáticos do seu site e os entrega pra o cliente. Isso faz com que a carga seja reduzida.

Por esse motivo no site de verificação de performance você recebeu a mensagem: 
"Use a CDN for all static assets", ou seja, ele está falando para você usar um CDN para os arquivos estáticos.

A implementação completa e uma boa explicação podem ser vistas nesse [site](http://hippocurious.com/setup-a-cdn-to-speed-up-your-website/).

Answer (score 0):

Content Delivery Network (CDN ou Rede de Fornecimento de Conteúdo), são servidores que fornecem conteúdo. Normalmente, para implementá-lo, é inserir uma fonte externa ao projeto. Exemplo:

Local

```
<script src="../caminho/script.js"></script>
```

CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seria legal explicar qual a função principal do CDN.