# Quando incluímos um arquivo de script ou CSS no documento HTML, acontece uma requisição HTTP?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http

**Por exemplo:** `<script src="file.js" > </script>`  **ou**  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >`

**Dúvida:** Quando fazemos isso, ocorre *request* HTTP? Seria mais performático se eu não fizesse isso, e colocasse tudo direto no documento HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, para cada arquivo referenciado haverá uma requisição diferente.

Seria mais performático carregar tudo em um arquivo só, até mesmo as imagens, economiza alguns *round trips* ao servidor e no final será mais rápido.

Mas não necessariamente oferecerá uma experiência melhor para o usuário. É possível que o usuário fique esperando mais tempo para ver a página montada já que a carga é única. Se for trazendo coisas menores aos poucos já pode ir montando e começar aprender algo antes.

Se as mesmas coisas forem necessárias em outra página, e é muito comum que isto ocorra, muito mesmo, vai ter que transmitir de novo. Uma vez que isto ocorra a vantagem já foi pro brejo. Separar permite o reaproveitamento.

Hoje se faz muita requisição depois via AJAX ou algo assim. Cada vez mais vemos carregamento ocorrendo em partes. Claro que até poderia estar todo mundo fazendo errado, mas acha que se todos estão fazendo assim não deve ser melhor assim na maioria dos casos. Claro que cada caso é um caso. Não gosto quando todo mundo adota um caminho único sem ver o contexto. Seu caso pode se beneficiar mais se juntar tudo, vai saber...

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe requisicão http pra cada chamada.
Na questão de performance pode ser que sim, se for algo pequeno, e pode ser que não, caso seja muita coisa, pois ao inves de fazer varias requisições pequenas , você ira fazer apenas uma requisição grande, o que pode diminuir a performance ao invés de aumentar.

O melhor é fazer o teste monitorando pela aba Network do DevTools e verificar em quanto tempo sua pagina é carregada.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é minificar os seus arquivos javascript e css, para que eles fiquem menores e o download deles seja feito mais rapido.

Answer (score 1):

## Separado é melhor que Junto

Veja como funciona o fluxo Navegador <-> Servidor: Você digita a `URL` no navegador e a requisição (*Request*) é feita ao servidor. O servidor, depois de processar seja lá o que for do lado dele, vai devolver UMA resposta (*Response*). O protocolo (`HTTP`) funciona assim. Uma requisição -> Uma resposta. Não tem como te dar mais de uma resposta para uma requisição.

O que o navegador faz? Ele processa o `HTML` e para cada dependência que ele encontra vai fazer novas requisições ao servidor para buscar a informação que precisa.

A questão de ter melhor ou pior desempenho colocando tudo no corpo da página e vir tudo na mesma requisição depende de alguns fatores, mas no geral não faz sentido.

Por exemplo, o seu servidor vai servir apenas 1 cliente? Seu `CSS` ou `Script` está hospedado em um [`CDN`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168575/o-que-%C3%A9-cdn-e-como-habilit%C3%A1-lo-nos-meus-arquivos-javascript)? Você tem um controle no servidor para dizer ao navegador que o `CSS` ou Script que ele está baixando não teve alteração e você pode usar o que estiver no cache do browser?

Na maioria dos casos a resposta é que os servidores Web são feitos para atender ao maior número de requisições possíveis no menor tempo possível e assim poder ter mais clientes atendidos pelo mesmo processo. E se a sua aplicação não colaborar para que isso aconteça você estará matando o servidor web e provavelmente seu sistema terá dificuldades de escalabilidade.

Em resumo: O melhor seria você quebrar as partes ao invés de deixar tudo no mesmo `HTML`. #tamoseparado