# Consulta simples do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Sei muito pouco de SQL e estou pensando num sistema muito simples - mas não sei montá-lo e é para uma escola pública que não tem como contratar um programador no momento.

Tenho uma tabela no SQL com alguns dados de cadastro dos alunos e cada um tem um ID. Queria montar um sistema com PHP com apenas um campo no qual eu digitaria esse ID e com um Enter ele exibisse todos os dados para confirmar.

Não sei se usei todos os códigos corretos e se o chamei corretamente no PHP. Eu dei uma pesquisada e encontrei um código AJAX para isso, mas também não sei se está tudo certo... Segue o que tenho até agora:

## Arquivo index.js

```
//Classe para criar e configurar requisição ajax
var Ajax = function() {
    'use strict';

    var request;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var url;
    var data;
    var method;

    var getUrl = function() {
        return url;
    }
    var setUrl = function(v) {
        url = v;
    }

    var getData = function() {
        return data;
    }
    var setData = function(v) {
        data = v;
    }

    var getMethod = function() {
        return method;
    }
    var setMethod = function(v) {
        method = v;
    }

    var send = function(loading, done) {
        if (!url) throw new Error('Url esperada.');
        if (!method) {
            console.warn('Metodo não especificado. Presumido POST.');
            method = 'POST';
        }

        request.onprogress = function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable && loading) {
                var percentComplete = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
                loading(percentComplete);
            }
        };

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200 && request.responseText && done) {
                done(request.responseText.toString().replace('while(1);', ''));
            }
        };

        request.open(method, url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf8');
        request.send(data);
    }

    //Métodos ou propriedades públicas da classe
    return {
        //Significa que quando instanciar a classe,
        //O objeto terá o método 'getUrl', por exemplo.
        //Quando o mesmo for executado: instancia.getUrl
        //Será executada a função 'getUrl', definida acima 'var getUrl = function..'
        getUrl: getUrl,
        setUrl: setUrl,
        getData: getData,
        setData: setData,
        getMethod: getMethod,
        setMethod: setMethod,
        send: send
    }
}

var campoid = document.getElementById('campoid');

campoid.onblur = function() {
    //Instancia a classe Ajax
    var requestid = new Ajax();

    //Configura a requisição
    requestid.setUrl('/conecta.php');
    requestid.setData('ID = ' + this.value);
    requestid.setMethod('POST');
    //Envia a requisição
    requestid.send(null,
    function(resposta) {
        //falha na busca, id ausente
        if (!resposta) {
            alert('ID não encontrado');
            campoid.focus();
            campoid.clear();
            return false;
        }
        //não precisa de else, o return false acima termina a execução da função

        //Transforma a string que o PHP criou em um objeto (JSON)
        var dados = JSON.parse(resposta);

        document.getElementById('outrocampodoform').value = dados.nome;
    });
}
</script>
```

## Arquivo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Central</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,300|Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <php include 'conecta.php' ?></php>
      <div class="field" align="center">
          <label>ID: </label>
          <input name="id" id="id" placeholder="ID" tabindex="3" required maxlength="10" onblur="ajax.js" autofocus>
      </div><br>
      <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Nome: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="nome" id="nome" type="text" disabled>
      </div><br>    
      <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Status: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="status" id="status" type="text" disabled> 
      </div><br>     
      <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Documento: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="documento" id="documento" type="text" disabled>
      </div><br>
          <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Nascimento: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" type="text" disabled>
      </div><br>
      <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Instituição: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="instituicao" id="escola" type="text" disabled>
      </div><br>
      <div class="field" align="center">
            <label>Validade: </label> <input class="input-tam-1" name="validade" id="validade" type="text" disabled>
      </div><br> 
  </body>
</html>
```

## Arquivo conecta.php

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "wjr_estudante";
$user = "wjr_estudante";
$pass = "xdr56tfc";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT ID, NOME, STATUS, DOCUMENTO, NASCIMENTO, INSTITUICAO, VALIDADE FROM estudantes WHERE NOME = ". $nome");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);

 //Jogar dentro dessa $results os resultados da query


    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0)
    {
        $i = 0;

        //Pega os resultados e transforma em um array
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
            $campos = array_keys($result);
            foreach($campos as $campo)
            {
                $allData[$i][$campo] = $result[$campo];
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo "while(1);" . json_encode($allData);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Pode fazer um isso com ajax e uma consulta sql pelo ou um campo chamado matricula. Precisa dar mais detalhes sobre o seu problema e qual 'pé' ele está

Comment: Esse jquery foi o incorporador de códigos daqui que adicionou... Não usarei, não

Comment: O servidor roda PHP 5.6, mas posso alterar até o 7.1. A tabela tem colunas de ID, nome, status, data etc. Os mesmos que estão no formulário html e quero que retornem a partir da consulta do ID (único para cada cadastro).

Comment: Não, apenas consulta... Os dados vão pro db por outro sistema. Eu quero apenas digitar o ID pra que ele consulte os demais dados no sql e exiba no formulário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estarei assumindo a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `aluno` (
  `id_aluno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nascimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `instituicao` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validade` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `criado` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `alterado` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `aluno`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_aluno`);

ALTER TABLE `aluno`
  MODIFY `id_aluno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Vou levar em consideração que já desenvolveu um modo de cadastrar esses dados no sistema, caso seja necessário cadastrar, informe nos comentários.

A primeira coisa a se fazer é criar uma conexão com o banco de dados, veja que no seu exemplo vocÊ causa uma certa confusão com as extensões mysql e mysqli, a primeira foi descontinuada e você não poderá mais usa-la se você atualizar o php para a versão 7, então é **altamente** recomendável você passar a utilizar mysqli ou pdo, irei fazer um exemplo usando pdo.

## Arquivo conexao.php

Esse arquivo será igual tanto para as extensões mysqli quanto para pdo, o ideal é criar um arquivo a parte, para que fique fácil alterar se houver mais de um ambiente ou futuras migrações de sistema.

```
<?php
    // Host
    define("host","localhost");
    // Esquema
    define("schema","teste");
    // Usuário
    define("user","root");
    // senha
    define("password","");
?>
```

A função `define()` cria uma constante que poderá ser usada em qualquer parte do sistema e que não poderá ser alterada em códigos futuros.

## Arquivo funcoes.php

Nesse arquivo você pode concentrar funções auxiliares que irão ser úteis em mais de um script, como uma função que loga erros de script ou de cadastro ao banco de dados, por exemplo

```
<?php
    function create_log( $filename, $string ) {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
        file_put_contents( $filename.".log", date( 'r' )." ".$string.PHP_EOL.json_encode($_REQUEST).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }
```

> date_default_timezone_set -> Configura o fuso horário padrão utilizado
>   por todas as funções de data e hora em um script
>
> file_put_contents -> Escreve uma string em um arquivo
>
> date -> Formata a data e a hora local, no caso r no formato Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200
>
> json_encode -> Retorna a representação JSON de um valor

---

## Arquivo inicializa-sessao.php

Para tornar o sistema mais seguro, e bloquear o acesso externo, eu criaria um token na sessão que poderia ser gerado da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    // Inicializa a sessão, caso ainda não tenha sido inicializada
    session_start(); 
    // Seto que o retorno será como json
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    // A função crypto "criptografa" alguma string passada como parâmetro, e a função time retorna o timestamp atual do servidor, salvo a concatenação dentro de uma váriavel token que seto na sessão
    $_SESSION['token'] = crypt( "o4sddfgsa5dv4A2vDAaXta7aasdff87" . time(), "" );
    // Retorna um json com o token para ser usado futuramente
    die('{"token": "'.$_SESSION['token'].'"}');
?>
```

Lembrando que esse script não deve ser usado para gerar criptografia de senhas, ele vai gerar apenas um chave de acesso momentânea para a api

Eu faria algumas modificações no seu arquivo index.php, primeiro converteria para .html, quando o servidor detecta que o arquivo solicitado possui a extensão .php, ele obrigatoriamente chama o interpretador php, no seu caso na página em si não há muita necessidade de consumir recursos do servidor nesse momento, então eu converteria para .html. Outro ponto são as bibliotecas, uma dica interessante é sempre que possível, para conteúdos estáticos, tipo bibliotecas externas, utilizar cdn, claro que é mais opcional do que qualquer coisa, mas fica a seu critério, deixo um [conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168580/14262) sobre cdn caso queira se iterar mais sobre o assunto.

Outras ressalvas, no seu arquivo index.php você comete dois erros de sintaxe, o primeiro: `<php include 'conecta.php' ?></php>`, php não é uma tag html que deve ser usada como outras tipo `<table>`, `<img>`, etc. Quando o interpretador php é chamado no servidor ele busca todas as aberturas da tag `<?php` e interpreta tudo o que está contido até o fechamento desta tag, que é `?>`, nessa linha também falta um `;`, ela deveria ser: `<?php include 'conecta.php'; ?>`.

O segundo erro está na chamada do evento `onblur` do input id, `onblur="ajax.js"` ... os evento das tags html devem chamar funções javascript, ou executar funções javascript, e não carregar arquivos javascript, a única tag que pode carregar um arquivo javascript externo é a tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/do/seu/js.js"></script>`, ou se quiser incluir o script na própria página basta fazer do seguinte modo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Seu código aqui!
     .
     .
     .
    */
</script>
```

## Arquivo index.html

Com as alterações e ressalvas, eu criaria um arquivo assim:

```html
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Central</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,300|Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- O evento onload chama a função iniciarSessao() apos toda a página html ser carregada -->

<body onload="iniciarSessao()">
  <!-- Input token tipo hidden -->
  <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden">
  <!-- Div mostra mensagem de retorno caso haja erro -->
  <div id="retorno" name="retorno" align="center"></div>
  <!-- Form apenas para ficar mais conveniente na hora de limpar os campos -->
  <div class="field" align="center">
    <label>ID: </label>
    <!-- O evento onblur chama a função pesquisarAluno() com o valor digitado apos cada alteração no valor do input -->
    <input id="id" name="id" placeholder="ID" tabindex="3" required maxlength="10" onblur="pesquisarAluno(this.value)">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <form id="form">
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Nome: </label>
      <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Status: </label>
      <input id="status" name="status" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Documento: </label>
      <input id="documento" name="documento" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Nascimento: </label>
      <input id="nascimento" name="nascimento" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Instituição: </label>
      <input id="instituicao" name="escola" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field" align="center">
      <label>Validade: </label>
      <input id="validade" name="validade" type="text" class="input-tam-1" disabled>
    </div>
    <br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Arquivo index.js

Sua intenção é utilizar ajax puro, sem utilizar jquery, eu montaria desta forma:

```
// Função cria um token e seta o valor no input com id token
var iniciarSessao = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // chamo o script php inicializa-sessao.php criado anteriormente
    request.open('GET', 'inicializa-sessao.php', true);
    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("token").value = data.token;
        }else{
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    };
    request.send();
}

// Função pesquisa o aluno e seta os valores de retorno em seus respectivos campos 
var pesquisarAluno = function(id){
    var token = document.getElementById("token").value;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // chamo o script php consulta.php setando como query string token e id_aluno
    request.open('GET', 'consulta.php?token='+token+'&id_aluno='+id, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("nome").value = data.nome;
            document.getElementById("status").value = data.status;
            document.getElementById("documento").value = data.documento;
            document.getElementById("nascimento").value = data.nascimento;
            document.getElementById("instituicao").value = data.instituicao;
            document.getElementById("validade").value = data.validade;
        }else{
            form.reset();
            document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = "<b>"+data.msg+"</b>";
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
```

## Arquivo consulta.php

Por fim mas não menos importante o arquivo que vai fazer a consulta no servidor

```
<?php
    // Inicializo a sessão que já foi criada anteriormente
    session_start();
    $token = ( empty( $_GET['token'] ) ? "" : $_GET['token'] );
    // Seto o cabeçalho html para aceitar requisições de qualquer lugar, utilizando o método GET, e que responda no formato json
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    /*
    As funções abaixo habilitam um modo de depuração mais adequado pra um ambiente de homologação ou de testes, não recomendo usar em produção por que possibilita expor a sua infraestrutura ou suas funções para quem acessar o script de fora
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    */
    // Se o token não estiver mais setado, significa que a conexão expirou, então retorno um http status 401 Unauthorized (Não autorizado), ou seja a pessoa que tentou acessar não está mais autorizada a utilizar o mesmo token
    if( ! isset( $_SESSION['token'] ) ){
        http_response_code(401);
        die('{"msg": "Conexão perdida."}');
    }
    // Se o token estiver vazio, ou for diferente do token de sessão, provavelmente houve alguma tentativa de burlar o sistema, retorno o mesmo http status 401 Unauthorized (Não autorizado)
    if( empty( $_SESSION['token'] ) || $_SESSION['token'] != $token ) {
        http_response_code(401);
        die('{"msg": "Acesso Negado."}');
    }
    // Se não houver a váriavel id_aluno ou ela vier vazia, retorno o http status 404 Not Found (Não Encontrado)
    if( empty($_GET['id_aluno']) ) {
        http_response_code(404);
        die('{"msg": "Aluno não encontrado."}');
    }

    // Se não houver nenhum erro até aqui, posso começar o sistema sem mais preocupações, insiro as constantes da conexão com o banco de dados e as funções auxiliares que poderão ser utilizadas
    require_once "conexao.php";
    require_once "funcoes.php";

    try {
        // Crio a variável de conexão dentro de um bloco try...catch
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".host.";dbname=".schema.";charset=utf8;", user, password);
        /*
        Só deve ser usado se uma transação do tipo insert, alter ou delete for necessária
        $db->beginTransaction();
        */
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
        create_log("logs/db_errors","Conexão".PHP_EOL."Exceção: ".$e);
        die('{"msg": "Erro interno do servidor."}');
    }

    $retorno = procurar_usuario($db, "id", "*");
    if(empty($retorno)){
        http_response_code(404);
        die('{"msg": "Aluno não encontrado."}');
    }else{
        die(json_encode($retorno));
    }

    function procurar_usuario($db, $parameter, $arguments) {
        switch ($parameter) {
            case 'id':
                $sql = "SELECT ".$arguments." FROM aluno WHERE id_aluno = ?";
                try {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute(array( 
                        $_GET['id_aluno']
                    ));
                    $db_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    http_response_code(500);
                    create_log( "logs/db_errors", "Search customer".PHP_EOL.$parameter.PHP_EOL.$arguments.PHP_EOL."Exception: ".$e );
                    die('{"msg": "Erro interno do servidor."}');
                }
                break;
            default:
                http_response_code(404);
                die('{"msg": "Método não encontrado."}');
        }
        return $db_data;
    }
?>
```

Para entender o funcionamento do bloco [try...catch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58549/14262)

No final, a cara do seu sistema deverá ser mais ou menos essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Resposta em desenvolvimento.

Comment: Criei a tabela que você assumiu, até a testei e ok... Mas o que eu coloco no arquivo inicializa-sessao.php? Pq chama ele no js e insere o token no pedido com o id_aluno, como eu faço pra gerar o token?

Comment: Estou rodando no Chrome mas não retornou com os resultados, no Console está dando Uncaught ReferenceError: iniciarSessao is not defined at onload ((index):15)... Não entendi, o js está chamado no head

Comment: Consegui! Acabei acrescentando um caractere sem querer no index.js
Ele consultou o banco certinho, sem problemas! Como eu faço pra inserir um botão que após a consulta ele fique no foco pra atualizar a página e limpar o formulário? Ou seja... A pessoa insere o código e com um Enter ela possa limpar para consultar o próximo

Comment: @WilliamGerrit entenda que a própria pergunta já deveria ter sido fechada pelo motivo de não ter um escopo definido e por ser muito ampla, veja que a resposta ficou imensa, fora dos padrões da comunidade..... sugiro que leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/14262) e principalmente [Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/14262)

Comment: Sugiro primeiramente que caso houver mais alguma dúvida, faça outra pergunta, e defina um escopo com um [mcve] e ainda faça o [tour] para entender como funciona a comunidade SOpt