# O que significa distribuir conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados no CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-aws

Vi em um [site](https://amaro.com), o CloudFront, e me parece que o site fica mais rápido por conta disso.

Li sobre isso:

> "O Amazon CloudFront é um serviço Web que oferece às empresas e aos desenvolvedores de aplicativos uma maneira fácil e de baixo custo de **distribuir conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados**."

Tudo bem, entendi mais ou menos, mas gostaria de entender melhor, o que seria *distribuir conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados*?

O site supracitado, por exemplo usa isso nas imagens, se você pegar o link das imagens por exemplo, vai ver.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é CDN e como habilitá-lo nos meus arquivos JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168575/o-que-%c3%a9-cdn-e-como-habilit%c3%a1-lo-nos-meus-arquivos-javascript)

Comment: Não responde em nada minha pergunta, Marcelo. Não é CloudFlare, e sim CloudFront.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade Quase certeza que a pergunta dele é especificamente sobre o serviço da Amazon.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis Isso mesmo.

Comment: Se não for por duplicata, será por ampla demais.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade No que ela é ampla?

Comment: Veja a própria definição no site: [Rede de entrega de conteúdo (CDN) global altamente seguro](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/cloudfront/). Explicar o funcionamento da ferramenta e como utilizar dá-se de `N`maneiras.

Comment: Marcelo, eu queria saber melhor o que é "distribuir conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados."

Comment: Como ele faz isso?

Comment: Ele só quer saber uma base, bem provavelmente. Nós temos vários posts que perguntam "O que é X?" e são bem aceitos/respondidos. Não vejo o porquê deste caso ser diferente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CloudFront

O Amazon *CloudFront* é uma rede de entrega de conteúdo global (CDN) que entrega dados, vídeos, aplicativos e APIs aos espectadores com segurança, *baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência*.

Leitura recomendada: [O que é CDN e como habilitá-lo nos meus arquivos JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168575/66203).

O *CloudFront* é integrado à Amazon Web Service (AWS) em dois níveis:

- As localizações físicas, que são conectadas diretamente à infraestrutura global da AWS;
- E o software, que trabalha diretamente com serviços como AWS Shield para mitigação de DDoS, Amazon S3, Elastic Load Balancing ou Amazon EC2 como origens para aplicativos e AWS Lambda para execução de código personalizado perto dos espectadores.

Leitura recomendada: [Amazon Web Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/aws/info)

#### O que significa distribuir conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados no CloudFront?

De acordo com a própria definição contida no [site da Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/cloudfront/):

> O AWS *CloudFront*, acelera a entrega de conteúdo estático (por exemplo, imagens, folhas de estilo, JavaScript, etc), pois oferece um cache multicamada com **pontos de presença de caches regionais que reduzem a latência e a carga dos servidores** de origem quando o objeto ainda não está no cache do ponto de presença;

De acordo com a própria Amazon existem, 44 zonas de disponibilidade em 16 regiões geográficas ... e mais 82 pontos de presença e 11 pontos de presença de cache regionais em 23 países e 49 cidades, garantindo que os aplicativos proporcionem alta disponibilidade, escalabilidade e desempenho.

> O **armazenamento de conteúdo estático em cache proporciona o desempenho e a escala necessários para entregar aos espectadores uma experiência rápida e confiável** quando visitam o seu site.

Também comentado no site oficial, a Amazon fala que seu roteamento inteligente do *CloudFront* que é baseado em medidas de latência do mundo real, coletadas a todo momento, juntamente com centenas de provedores de serviços de Internet de usuários finais e uso de rede backbone da AWS, permite acelerar a entrega do conteúdo de ponta a ponta.

---

Vale ressaltar que o principal, para **garantir** a distribuição de conteúdo com baixa latência e altas velocidades de transferência de dados **é a presença de cache regional**.

Answer (score 1):

> Esta resposta veio antes da edição da pergunta, irei editar ou remover, ainda estou analisando se é possível salvar algo

O link explica como o funciona o comportamento entre os servidores:

- [*Como o CloudFront oferece conteúdo*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html)

Mas o que entendo pela sua pergunta é que você talvez queira saber como configurar, conforme este link [*Conceitos básicos do CloudFront*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html)

## Conceitos básicos do CloudFront

O exemplo deste tópico fornece uma rápida visão geral de como usar o CloudFront para:

Armazene versões originais de seus objetos em um bucket do Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).
Distribua o download de conteúdo, como texto ou gráficos.
Deixe seus objetos acessível a todos.
Use o nome de domínio do CloudFront em URLs para seus objetos (por exemplo, http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/image.jpg), em vez de seu próprio nome de domínio (por exemplo, http://www.example.com/image.jpg).
Mantenha seus objetos em pontos de presença do CloudFront para a duração padrão de 24 horas. (A duração mínima é 0 segundos.)
Para obter informações sobre como usar o CloudFront quando você deseja usar outras opções, consulte Lista de tarefas para criar uma distribuição na Web ou Lista de tarefas para arquivos usando RTMP Streaming Media.

Você só precisa executar algumas etapas básicas para começar a entregar seu conteúdo usando CloudFront. A primeira etapa é se inscrever. Depois disso, você cria uma distribuição do CloudFront e, em seguida, use o nome de domínio do CloudFront para referenciar o conteúdo em suas páginas da web ou aplicativos.

### Etapa 1: cadastre-se na Amazon Web Services

Se você ainda não tiver feito isso, se cadastrar para a Amazon Web Services em http://aws.amazon.com. Basta escolher `Sign Up Now` e insira todas as informações necessárias.

### Etapa 2: Faça o upload de seu conteúdo para o Amazon S3 e conceder permissões de objeto

Um bucket do Amazon S3 é um contêiner que pode conter objetos ou pastas. CloudFront pode distribuir praticamente qualquer tipo de objeto para você usando um bucket do Amazon S3 como origem, por exemplo, texto, imagens e vídeos. Você pode criar vários buckets, e não há limite para a quantidade de dados que você pode armazenar no Amazon S3.

Por padrão, o bucket do Amazon S3 e todos os seus objetos são privados – somente a conta da AWS que criou o bucket tem permissão para ler ou gravar os objetos. Se você deseja permitir que qualquer pessoa para acessar objetos no bucket do Amazon S3 usando URLs do CloudFront públicos, você deve conceder permissões de leitura para os objetos. (Este é um dos erros mais comuns do CloudFront e ao trabalhar com o Amazon S3. Você deve conceder explicitamente privilégios para cada objeto em um bucket do Amazon S3.)

> nota Se você deseja restringir quem pode fazer o download de seu
>   conteúdo, você pode usar o recurso de conteúdo privado do CloudFront.
>   Para obter mais informações sobre a distribuição de conteúdo privado,
>   consulte Distribuição de conteúdo privado por meio do CloudFront. Para
>   fazer o upload de seu conteúdo para o Amazon S3 e conceder permissão
>   de leitura para todos

Faça login no Console de gerenciamento da AWS e abra o console da Amazon S3 em https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.

No console do Amazon S3, escolha Create Bucket.

Na caixa de Create Bucket diálogo, insira um nome de bucket.

Importante
Para o seu bucket para trabalhar com CloudFront, o nome deve estar de acordo com os requisitos de nomeação de DNS. Para obter mais informações, consulte Bucket Restrictions and Limitations no Guia do desenvolvedor do Amazon Simple Storage Service.
Selecione uma região para o seu bucket. Por padrão, o Amazon S3 cria buckets na região Leste dos EUA (Norte da Virgínia). Recomendamos que você escolher uma região perto de você para otimizar a latência, minimizar custos ou atender aos requisitos regulatórios.

Escolha Create.

Selecione seu bucket no Buckets painel e escolha Upload.

Na Upload - Select Files página, escolha Add Filese escolher os arquivos que você deseja carregar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ativar privilégios de leitura públicos para cada objeto que você enviar para seu bucket do Amazon S3.

Escolha Set Details.

Na Set Details página, escolha Set Permissions.

Na Set Permissions página, escolha Make everything public.

Escolha Start Upload.

Após o upload for concluída, você poderá navegar para este item ao seu URL. No caso do exemplo anterior, o URL seria:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/example-myawsbucket/filename

Use o URL do Amazon S3 para verificar se o seu conteúdo é acessível publicamente, mas lembre-se de que isso não é o URL utilizado quando você estiver pronto para distribuir seu conteúdo.

### Etapa 3: Crie uma distribuição de web do CloudFront

Para criar uma distribuição de web do CloudFront

Abra o console do CloudFront em https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/.

Escolha Create Distribution.

Na Select a delivery method for your content página, na Web seção, escolha Get Started.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na Create Distribution página, sob Origin Settings, escolha o bucket do Amazon S3 que você criou anteriormente. Para Origin ID, Origin Path, Restrict Bucket Accesse Origin Custom Headers, aceite os valores padrão.

[image: Especifique o bucket do Amazon S3.]

Em Default Cache Behavior Settings, aceite os valores padrão e do CloudFront serão:

Encaminhe todas as solicitações que usam o URL do CloudFront para a sua distribuição (por exemplo, http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/image.jpg) para o bucket do Amazon S3 que você especificou na Etapa 4.
Permitir que os usuários finais para usar o HTTP ou HTTPS para acessar seus objetos.
Responder a solicitações de seus objetos.
seus objetos em cache os pontos de presença do CloudFront para 24 horas.
Encaminhe somente os cabeçalhos de solicitação padrão para sua origem e não em cache os objetos com base nos valores dos cabeçalhos.
Excluir cookies e parâmetros de sequência de caracteres de consulta, se houver, ao encaminhar as solicitações de objetos para sua origem. (Amazon S3 não processar cookies e processa apenas um conjunto limitado de parâmetros de sequência de caracteres de consulta.)
Não ser configurado para distribuir arquivos de mídia no formato Microsoft Smooth Streaming.
Permitir que qualquer pessoa para visualizar seu conteúdo.
Não compactar automaticamente o seu conteúdo.
Para obter mais informações sobre as opções de comportamento de cache, consulte Configurações de comportamento de cache.

[image: Definir comportamento de cache.]

Em Distribution Settings, insira os valores aplicáveis:

Classe de preço
Selecione a classe de preço que corresponde com o preço máximo que deseja pagar por serviço do CloudFront. Por padrão, o CloudFront oferece seus objetos a partir de pontos de presença em todas as regiões do CloudFront.

Para obter mais informações sobre classes de preços e sobre como sua escolha de classe de preço afeta o desempenho do CloudFront para a sua distribuição, vá para Escolha a classe de preço para uma distribuição do CloudFront. Para obter informações sobre a definição de preço do CloudFront, incluindo como mapear classes de preço para regiões do CloudFront, vá para o Amazon CloudFront de preço.

A AWS WAF ACL Web
Se você quiser usar a AWS WAF para permitir ou bloquear as solicitações HTTP e HTTPS com base em critérios que você especificar, escolha o ACL da web para associar a essa distribuição. Para obter mais informações sobre a AWS WAF WAF da AWS, consulte o Guia do desenvolvedor.

Alternar nomes de domínio (CNAMEs) (Opcional)
Especifique um ou mais nomes de domínio que você deseja usar para URLs para seus objetos em vez do nome de domínio que ele atribui quando você cria sua distribuição. Por exemplo, se você deseja que o URL para o objeto:

```
/images/image.jpg
```

para o seguinte:

```
http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg
```

em vez de:

```
http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg
```

você deve criar um CNAME para www.example.com.

Importante
Se você adicionar um CNAME para www.example.com a sua distribuição, você também precisa criar (ou atualizar) um registro CNAME com o serviço DNS para rotear as consultas para www.example.com a d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net. Você deve ter permissão para criar um registro CNAME com o provedor de serviço de DNS para o domínio. Normalmente, isso significa que você possui o domínio, mas você também pode ser o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo para o domínio proprietário. Para obter mais informações sobre CNAMEs, consulte Usando Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs).
Para saber mais sobre o limite do número de nomes de domínio alternativo que você pode adicionar a uma distribuição, consulte o Amazon CloudFront Limits no Referência geral do Amazon Web Services. Para solicitar um limite maior, vá para https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-cloudfront-distributions.

Certificado SSL
Aceite o valor padrão, Default CloudFront Certificate.

Objeto raiz padrão (Opcional)
O objeto que você deseja que a solicitação do CloudFront de sua origem (por exemplo, index.html) quando um visualizador solicita o URL raiz de sua distribuição (http://www.example.com/) em vez de um objeto em sua distribuição (http://www.example.com/product-description.html). Especificando um objeto de raiz padrão evita expor o conteúdo de sua distribuição.

Logging (Opcional)
Se você deseja que o CloudFront para registrar informações sobre cada solicitação para um objeto e armazenar os arquivos de log em um bucket do Amazon S3, selecione One especifique o bucket e um prefixo opcional para os nomes dos arquivos de log. Não há custo adicional para habilitar o registro em log, mas você provisiona habituais cobranças do Amazon S3 para armazenar e acessar os arquivos. CloudFront não excluir os logs automaticamente, mas você pode excluí-los a qualquer momento.

Registro de cookies
Neste exemplo, estamos usando o Amazon S3 como a origem de seus objetos e o Amazon S3 não processar cookies, portanto, recomendamos que você selecione Off para o valor de Cookie Logging.

Comentário (Opcional)
Informe os comentários que você deseja salvar com a distribuição.

Estado de distribuição
Selecione esta Enabled opção se você deseja que as solicitações para iniciar o processamento do CloudFront assim que a distribuição é criado, ou selecione Disabled se não quiser que as solicitações para iniciar o processamento do CloudFront depois que a distribuição é criado.

[image: configuraçõesdedistribuição]

Escolha Create Distribution.

Depois que tiver criado sua distribuição do CloudFront, o valor da Status coluna para a sua distribuição será alterado de InProgress para Deployed. Se você optar por habilitar a distribuição, ele será, então, pronto para processar solicitações. Isso deve demorar menos de 15 minutos.

O nome de domínio que atribui para a sua distribuição do CloudFront aparece na lista de distribuições. (Ele também é exibido na General guia para uma distribuição selecionada.)

### Etapa 4: Teste seus links

Depois de criar a distribuição, ele sabe onde o servidor de origem é Amazon S3 e você souber o nome de domínio associados com a distribuição. Você pode criar um link para o seu bucket do Amazon S3 conteúdo com esse nome de domínio e fazer com que ele servir.

> nota: Você deve aguardar até que o status de sua distribuição alterações Deployed antes de testar seus links.

Para vincular seus objetos

Copie o seguinte HTML em um novo arquivo:

Substitua nome de  com o nome de domínio que atribuídas a sua distribuição do CloudFront.
Substitua nome do  com o nome de um arquivo em seu bucket do Amazon S3.
Copy

```
<html>
<head>My CloudFront Test</head>
<body>
<p>My text content goes here.</p>
<p><img src="http://domain name/object name" alt="my test image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Por exemplo, se o seu nome de domínio d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net e seu objeto foi image.jpg, o URL do link seria:

```
 http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/image.jpg.
```

Se o objeto está em uma pasta no seu bucket, incluem a pasta no URL. Por exemplo, se image.jpg está localizado em uma pasta de imagens e, em seguida, o URL seria:

```
 http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg
```

Salve o texto em um arquivo que tem uma extensão de nome de arquivo.html.

Abra a página da web em um navegador para garantir que você pode ver o seu conteúdo. Se você não pode ver o conteúdo, confirme se você executou todas as etapas corretamente. Você também pode ver as dicas em Solução de problemas.

O navegador retorna a página com o arquivo de imagem incorporado, fornecido de presença do CloudFront determinado foi apropriado para servir o objeto.

> Ainda estou ajustando a marcação, copiei o texto e ele foi traduzido automaticamente

Comment: Fiz a edição para tentar *desampliar a pergunta* como foi debatido nos comentários. Ao meu ver acredito que uma edição (sinta-se livre para fazer/reverter) poderia 'salvar' mais a sua resposta porque ela foi muita bem desenvolvida.

Comment: E creio também que não há nenhum problema em mantê-la, já que faz todo um *tutorial* para uso do CloudFront inicial.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis me parece uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 0):

O CloudFront simplesmente pega o conteúdo do Servidor de Origem e faz a distribuição para diversos Pontos de Presença espalhados pelo mundo em cima da rede da Amazom. A partir daí, quando o usuário faz o acesso é roteado para o Ponto de Presença que estiver mais próximo dele. Como essa distância é menor geralmente do que ir até o Servidor de Origem buscar os dados, a latência é menor. Lembrando que latência é o tempo de ida e volta, ou seja, quanto tempo leva para a requisição sair do seu computador, bater no servidor e voltar para o seu computador.

Abraços,

Airton

---

devcontent.com.br